# How do I install azpainter 2.0.6?

Tags: software-installation, compiling

I'm a complete newbie with using Ubuntu (have only been using Windows my entire life) and I'm trying to install AZpainter 2.0.6. I got the download here: http://frankqbe.deviantart.com/art/AzPainter-212-English-Version-Download-488404806

I've spent a few hours trying to figure out what the first step here is asking me to do.

> 1. `cd' to the directory containing the package's source code and type
>       `./configure' to configure the package for your system.
>
>    Running `configure' might take a while.  While running, it prints
>       some messages telling which features it is checking for.

From what I understand, this means I compile from source? Not sure.

So Ive been following this guide here: http://www.control-escape.com/linux/lx-swinstall-tar.html and have only got to the step where I put `~/Downloads/azpainter-2.0.6 ./configure` into the terminal.

But what I get is:

```
bash: /home/dave/Downloads/azpainter-2.0.6: Is a directory
```

It seems others installing azpainter have found it really easy. But because I'm a newbie, I guess I'm not understanding the terminology.

Feeling somewhat sad and frustrated I cant get this paint program to install (already had similar issues trying to get paint tool said to work through playonlinux- I swear its because I don't know what I'm doing or what any of the terminology means). So any help at all would be really appreciated. THanks!

Answer (score 4):

To compile azpainter from source code, download and unpack the source code archive, check for documentation on how to install, install whatever build dependencies you determine are necessary, and run `./configure` and `make` as instructed by the documentation.

While that is also a good general pattern for compiling software from source code, the rest of this post is a step-by-step walkthrough for azpainter, including some useful information not currently provided in the official installation instructions. **I have tested this in Ubuntu 14.04 LTS and Ubuntu 16.04 LTS.**

#### Getting the Source Code

Suppose you have downloaded azpainter 2.0.6 (later readers [can check here](https://osdn.net/projects/azpainter/releases/p14000) for other versions):

```bash
wget https://osdn.net/dl/azpainter/azpainter-2.0.6.tar.bz2
```

If you run a command like that, or download it in your web browser, you don't get a folder--you get a `.tar.bz2` archive which you must unpack in order to use. To unpack it you would make sure you're in whatever directory contains it (you can use the `cd` command for that) and run:

```
tar xf azpainter-2.0.6.tar.bz2
```

For that particular archive, this creates an `azpainter-2.0.6` directory, which you can enter with `cd`:

```
cd azpainter-2.0.6
```

#### Determining Build Dependencies

**When compiling software you're unfamiliar with from source code, you should always check for files that provide instructions.** Reading the `README` file in this directory (you can also view its contents in your graphical file browser, if you like) contains a list of "What you need to compile." It also lists specific packages (scroll down to "Debian/Ubuntu") that you can install to provide what it needs.

Although it's okay to install `gcc` and `make` directly, I suggest installing the `build-essential` package, which causes those packages to be installed, as well as a number of other tools that are frequently useful in compiling software.

When you install azpainter, the [`gtk-update-icon-cache`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/en/man1/gtk-update-icon-cache.1.html) command is used to attempt to create an easy graphical launcher for the program and to make them immediately available through your menus. Usually this succeeds; if not, and you want a launcher, you can make it yourself (see below). Furthermore, the [`update-desktop-database`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/en/man1/update-desktop-database.1.html) command is used to update the database of file types and what applications are capable of opening them. However, depending on what [release](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Releases) and [flavor](https://www.ubuntu.com/about/about-ubuntu/flavours) of Ubuntu you are running, these two commands might not be installed, so I suggest installing the packages that provide them, which are `libgtk2.0-bin` and `desktop-file-utils`, respectively.

Therefore I suggest running these commands to obtain the necessary build dependencies for azpainter:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install build-essential libx11-dev libxext-dev libxi-dev libfreetype6-dev libfontconfig1-dev zlib1g-dev libjpeg-dev libpng-dev libpng12-dev libgtk2.0-bin desktop-file-utils
```

(The instructions advise installing `libpng-dev` for some versions of Ubuntu and `libpng12-dev` for others, but if you like you can just install both as shown above.)

#### Compiling and Installing the Software

The next section of the `README` file tells you what commands you can run to install the software, once you've installed the build dependencies (see above). You should run these commands from inside the directory you unpacked that contains the `configure` script:

```
./configure
make
sudo make install-strip
```

Using the `install-strip` target instead of the `install` target strips debug symbols from the installed binaries, making them smaller. The `README` file recommends this, which is why I have shown it.

This installs the program in `/usr/local`--different parts of it will be placed in different subdirectories therein (which is typical). Specifically, the `azpainter` executable itself will be in `/usr/local/bin`. If that directory is in your [`$PATH`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PATH_(variable)#Unix_and_Unix-like) then you can simply run `azpainter`; either way you can run the program as `/usr/local/bin/azpainter`.

#### Optional: Manually Creating a Launcher

You don't have to do anything else. However, it is *possible* no `.desktop` file for `azpainter` was successfully created.

A `.desktop` file is also called a launcher, and it makes it easier to run graphical programs by double-clicking icons or selecting them in menus. If you don't see it in your menus then [you may want to create one](https://askubuntu.com/questions/64222/how-can-i-create-launchers-on-my-desktop). You may be able to copy and use or modify the stock `.desktop` file included in the `desktop` subdirectory of the `azpainter-2.0.6` directory (i.e., the directory created by unpacking the source code).

If the program runs just by typing `azpainter` and pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd>, then the stock `.desktop` file included in the source archive should work without modification.

#### Optional: Uninstalling the Software

If you want to uninstall the software, you can do this by `cd`ing back to the directory where you ran `sudo make install-strip` (or `sudo make install`) and running:

```
sudo make uninstall
```

Not all programs and libraries that you build and install from source with `./configure` and `make` supports being uninstalled this way, but many do, including azpainter.

You may one day want to install. Even if you are very happy with the software, you may want to upgrade it to a later version, which for software you've manually installed from source like this is usually best achieved by uninstalling and then building and installing the newer version. Therefore I recommend you keep the `azpainter-2.0.6` (or whatever version you are using) directory and its contents.

However, if you do ever remove it, then you can regain the ability to uninstall by repeating the steps to install it, up to and including the `make` step.

- If you ever do this, you should use the *same* version of the software that was installed, starting from the same `.tar.bz2` archive. (For some programs, you have to actually run the `make install` or `make install-strip` step to get the ability to uninstall, but this does not appear to be necessary with azpainter.)
- You won't have to reinstall the packages you installed as build dependencies, though (i.e., no `apt` or `apt-get` commands required), unless you've subsequently removed them.

*Another way to manage installing, uninstalling, and upgrading packages you build yourself from source code is to use [`checkinstall`](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CheckInstall). See below for further reading that includes this and other useful general information not covered in this answer.*

#### Further Reading

To learn more about installing programs from source code, see:

- [CompilingEasyHowTo](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CompilingEasyHowTo)
- [How do I install a .tar.gz (or .tar.bz2) file?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/25961/how-do-i-install-a-tar-gz-or-tar-bz2-file)

Answer (score 4):

You could use [this PPA](https://launchpad.net/~alex-p/+archive/ubuntu/azpainter) as an alternative to installing from source:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:alex-p/azpainter
sudo apt update
sudo apt install azpainter
```

[More packages & discussion (in Russian)](https://www.linux.org.ru/forum/multimedia/13223232/).

Comment: +1 This is how most people will probably want to install AzPainter. I tested this PPA on 16.04 and it works. I think [my answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/942811) is still valuable, as the OP was interested in compiling, and it can be used on releases the PPA doesn't support. But the question here is how to install AzPainter, which this answers well. I'm guessing the downvote was before @Zanna's edit. (However, If the worry was about [security](https://askubuntu.com/q/35629/22949), note that [the PPA author](https://launchpad.net/~alex-p) is active in the community.)

Answer (score 0):

"~/Downloads/azpainter-2.0.6" is not part of the command you need to run, it is the directory you need to be in to run the command.

Run: `cd ~/Downloads/azpainter-2.0.6` to "change directory" into that directory.

For interest's sake, you can now run: `ls` to view the contents of that directory. In the list of files and directories, you should see "configure"

Now try running: `./configure` which literally runs "configure" as an executable.

Alternatively, you could simply run the command `./~/Downloads/azpainter-2.0.6/configure` which executes the file "configure" in the directory located at "~/Downloads/azpainter-2.0.6" from any directory.

Comment: Except for to deliberately build somewhere other than source directory (some programs suggest this, though most do not), `./configure` should be run from within the directory that contains the `configure` script. Whatever directory you run `configure` in may have files created in it as a result. For example, with azpainter `config.log` is created in whatever directory you run the script from. Furthermore, subsequent steps are not usually designed to be run from arbitrary directories. The next step here is to run `make`, which won't work (without command-line arguments) from another directory.